# Does not work script, that makes gzip for each log file of nginx

Tags: bash, shell, loops, find, gzip

Please, don't tell me about log rotation in unix, and other tools. I need this script.
When, i am trying to do this:

```
find /root/nginx.log* -type f -print0 -and ! -name "*.gz" -and ! -name "nginx.log.2017.05.08" -exec gzip "{}" \;
```

Everything is ok, i have this result, that i need:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1381791 May  8 10:33 nginx.log.2017.05.07.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 17942221 May  8 10:33 nginx.log.2017.05.08
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1381791 May  8 10:33 nginx.log.2017.05.09.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1381791 May  8 10:33 nginx.log.2017.05.10.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1381791 May  8 10:33 nginx.log.2017.05.11.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1381791 May  8 10:33 nginx.log.2017.05.12.gz
```

When i am trying to write script:

```
#!/bin/bash

name="nginx"
data=$(date +%Y.%m.%d)
current_nginx=$name.$data
echo $current_nginx

find /root/nginx.log* -type f -print0 -and ! -name "*.gz" -and ! -name "$current_nginx" -exec gzip "{}" \;
```

After executing of this script, i have:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1379440 May  8 10:35 nginx.log.2017.05.07.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1379440 May  8 10:35 nginx.log.2017.05.08.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1379440 May  8 10:35 nginx.log.2017.05.09.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1379440 May  8 10:35 nginx.log.2017.05.10.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1379440 May  8 10:35 nginx.log.2017.05.11.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1379440 May  8 10:35 nginx.log.2017.05.12.gz
```

Debug of script:

```
bash -x test.sh
+ name=nginx
++ date +%Y.%m.%d
+ data=2017.05.08
+ current_nginx=nginx.2017.05.08
+ echo nginx.2017.05.08
nginx.2017.05.08
+ find /root/nginx.log.2017.05.07.gz /root/nginx.log.2017.05.08.gz /root/nginx.log.2017.05.09.gz /root/nginx.log.2017.05.10.gz /root/nginx.log.2017.05.11.gz /root/nginx.log.2017.05.12.gz /root/nginx.log.2017.05.13.gz /root/nginx.log.2017.05.14.gz -type f -print0 -and '!' -name '*.gz' -and '!' -name nginx.2017.05.08 -exec gzip '{}' ';'
/root/nginx.log.2017.05.07.gz/root/nginx.log.2017.05.08.gz/root/nginx.log.2017.05.09.gz/root/nginx.log.2017.05.10.gz/root/nginx.log.2017.05.11.gz/root/nginx.log.2017.05.12.gz/root/nginx.log.2017.05.13.gz/root/nginx.log.2017.05.14.gz
```

My condition `-and ! -name "$current_nginx"` does not work. Where i have mistake ? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the .log in current_nginx